# Why do upgrades remove my r8168 module?

Tags: 11.10, kernel

I had terrible problems with Realtek RTL8111/8168B Ethernet which were solved by blacklisting the r8169 driver and instead using the r8168 driver that I downloaded from Realtek.

However, it seems that some updates remove the driver that I installed.  Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Does it work if you revert the changes (do not black list the module) and let the update do its work? Maybe the issues with the module where fixed on the new packages.

Comment: @BrunoPereira I'm not sure how to do that... but last time I had this upgrade issue, the r8169 was not blacklisted and the upgrade did indeed replace the r8168 module I installed with the r8169.  It was still horribly broken. I'd be interested in learning how the upgrades work so if you could link me to a good explanation that would be a very helpful answer for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrades do not remove your kernel module, it is just that a new kernel does not have the kernel module you installed. The new kernel is standard, it does not contain modules added by the user. So, every time a new kernel is installed, any non-standard modules have to be added by you.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks! I also note this problem has been fixed in a later kernel.